# Liquibase, "Migration Failed: Java heap space" error when generateChangeLog with "data"

Tags: java, database, refactoring, heap-memory, liquibase

I am trying to create a baseline on one of my development database using liquibase, here's my environment
- Database, -> Oralce 10g, with 500+ Tables with lots of configuration data, the oracle export dump file is about 70mb;
- Java - Java 6
- Oracle JDBC Driver - ojdbc14.jar (downloaded from Oracle web site)
- Command line execute
liquibase --changeLogFile=base.changelog.data.xml --diffTypes="data"  generateChangeLog

Execute result:
- Liquibase is configure to run with "-Xmx512m -Xms256m" jvm parameters, fail, error message - "Migration Failed: Java heap space
"
- configure to run with "-Xmx1024m -Xms512m", same error occurs
- configure to run with "-Xmx2048 -Xms512m", same error

What other options I have in oder to create base line for my development projects, so that we could start version control our db..

Appreciate ur advise, thanks!

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of liquibase are you using?  There has been some improvements in the performance of the diff support in the upcoming 2.0.  The latest build can be gotten from http://liquibase.org/ci/latest (once the bamboo server is fully upgraded)